# Why does scons ignore my CXXFlags in SConscript

Tags: c++, g++, scons

## Issue

When the command "scons" is run in the root directory, scons will eventually  run the command "g++ -o bin/program bin/cpp/main.o" which will return the error:

```
"undefined reference to 'dlopen', 'dlerror', 'dlsym', 'dlerror'"
```

This undefined reference issue can be resolved with the '-ldl' compile argument, but for some reason, scons won't append it.

How do I get scons to add the '-ldl' argument to the g++ command.

.

#### Project Setup

My project setup is as follows (simplified for stack overflow purposes):

```
projectFolder/
 ├──bin/
 │  ├─cpp/
 │  └─Future Compiled Binary
 │
 ├──cpp/
 │  ├─SConscript
 │  └─main.cpp
 │
 └──SConstruct
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

...

int main(void) {

    ...

}
```

#### SConscript

```
# C++
env = Environment()
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = '-ldl')
print env["CXXFLAGS"]

srcFiles = ['main.cpp']
env.Program('../program', srcFiles)
```

#### SConstruct

```
SConscript('cpp/SConscript', variant_dir='bin/cpp')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use CXXFLAGS to link libraries.  You should do this:

```
env.Program('../program', srcFiles, LIBS=['dl'])
```